# Splitting strings inside of list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, split

Although I've come across posts that seem to answer this, nothing I've tried from them have worked.

What I want to do is to turn a list like this:

```
["this is an\nexample" , "sentence\n\x0c"]
```

to this:

```
["this", "is", "an", "example", "sentence"]
```

I'm sure I'm massively overcomplicating this, and usually searching through forums for similar problems works, but for some reason nothing I've come across has been the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this (`map` returns you iterator which you directly sum with empty list to return the desired output in one go):

```
a = ["this is an\nexample" , "sentence\n\x0c"]
a = sum(map(str.split, a), [])
```

gives

```
['this', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'sentence']
```

Comment: How do you also apply ```.lower()``` cuz' I get an ```AttributeError: 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'lower'```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code.
Completely built-in [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), there are a lot of other functions there that might be useful to you.

```
from itertools import chain

s = ["this is an\nexample" , "sentence\n\x0c"]


s = [i.split() for i in s]

print(list(chain(*s)))
```

To make it even shorter like this. But I think the first one is better cause it's more **eyes friendly**.

```
from itertools import chain

s = ["this is an\nexample" , "sentence\n\x0c"]
print(list(chain(*[i.split() for i in s])))
```

**Output:**

```
['this', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'sentence']
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as using a string's split method.

```
l = ["this is an\nexample" , "sentence\n\x0c"]
l2 = []

for i in l:
    l2 += (i.split())
```